# Angular how continue method execution even if the http calls got error

Tags: angular, typescript, http

My http backend call may have exceptions, if it fails, my method doesn't continue with the rest of the instructions (//do something else). How to continue the execution even if there are exceptions?

```
  public updateStatus(status: string): void {
    this.userApiService.user.updateStatus(status, this.user.objectKey).subscribe((response) => {

      //do something else

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
public updateStatus(status: string): void 
{
    this.userApiService.user.updateStatus(status,this.user.objectKey)
    .pipe(finalize(() => 
    {
       //do something even after exception
    }), 
    .subscribe((response) => 
    {

    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: This approach is deprecated. Please wrap next, error, complete properties as functions in an object inside the subscribe method.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `catchError` operator.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

public updateStatus(status: string): void {
  this.userApiService.user.updateStatus(status,this.user.objectKey
    .pipe(
      catchError(e => /* handle error and return a handable error response */),
    ).subscribe((response) => {
      //do something else
    );
  }
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I would add also the import statement for 'catchError' Else the response is TOP :)

Comment: What i have to write in catchError? I got error of Expression expected

Comment: @ErvTheDev edited, good point, thx

Comment: @sweet e is the error object. You can use that to log the error, but after all you need to return a valid object or maybe null/undefined, which you can hande in the subscription